# Intersection of two lines with given point

Tags: vectors

How to solve this?
Find the line which passes through point of intersection of given two lines 
$\frac{x+2}{1}=\frac{y-3}{2}=\frac{z+1}{4}$ and $\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-2}{3}=\frac{z-3}{4}$, and passes through point $(1,1,1)$

Comment: At first i would compute the intersection point

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Your system is inconsistent so  these lines have no intersection.

Comment: You’re much more likely to get an answer instead of having your question closed if you show your own attempts at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

solve the equation System
$$t-2=2s+1$$
$$2t+3=3s+2$$
$$4t-1=4s+3$$ for $s,t$

Comment: This system is inconsistent.

Comment: this System was corrected!!

Comment: It still is inconsistent…

Comment: sorry a little typo!

Comment: Yes, but I mean  the system of the O.P. is inconsistent.

Comment: then there must be a mistake, which has made the OP